# knoppix syslinux.cfg config for booting

Tags: knoppix

I have installed Knoppix to my HDD, and I want if to boot with the cheatcode "fb800x600". I have added this to the APPEND line in /mnt-system/boot/syslinux/syslinux.cfg and /home/knoppix/Desktop/KNOPPIX/boot/syslinux/syslinux.cfg but to no avail. Please help! My Knoppix install is perfect appart from having to type "fb800x600" every time I boot up.

Thank-you for your time,

petemaxi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `/home/knoppix/Desktop/KNOPPIX` is a symlink to `/mnt-system`, so, as you may have already noticed, `/mnt-system/boot/syslinux/syslinux.cfg` and `/home/knoppix/Desktop/KNOPPIX/boot/syslinux/syslinux.cfg` is the same file.

The reason it didn't work by adding `fb800x600` to APPEND is, `fb800x600` is not a kernel parameter, but a syslinux boot entry, written at the latter part of exactly the same file:

```
LABEL fb800x600
KERNEL linux
APPEND lang=en apm=power-off vga=788 video=800x600 xmodule=fbdev initrd=minirt.gz nomce libata.force=noncq hpsa.hpsa_allow_any=1, loglevel=1
```

As you can see, it's simply another preset which has extra kernel parameters in its APPEND than the default `knoppix`/`knoppix64` entry (decided by the `auto` entry: http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=Ifcpu64.c32).

To make `fb800x600` the default, change:

```
DEFAULT auto
```

to:

```
DEFAULT fb800x600
```

The disadvantage of this method is it will skip the 64-bit CPU check in the `auto` entry. So you will always boot to 32-bit knoppix (which is also the case when you enter `fb800x600` manually on boot).

To avoid this, add the three extra params (`vga=788 video=800x600 xmodule=fbdev`) in the `APPEND` of `LABEL fb800x600` to that of `LABEL knoppix` and `LABEL knoppix64`.

Note that the `APPEND` after `DEFAULT auto` is apparently unused/useless, so don't add the three params there, it most likely won't work.

You can also instead add a 64-bit variant of the `fb800x600` entry:

```
LABEL fb800x600_64
KERNEL linux64
APPEND lang=en apm=power-off vga=788 video=800x600 xmodule=fbdev initrd=minirt.gz nomce libata.force=noncq hpsa.hpsa_allow_any=1, loglevel=1
```

And change:

```
LABEL auto
KERNEL ifcpu64.c32
APPEND knoppix64 -- knoppix
```

to:

```
LABEL auto
KERNEL ifcpu64.c32
APPEND fb800x600_64 -- fb800x600
```

Comment: I do not have a separate boot partition, and the file /boot/syslinux/syslinux.cfg does not exist. findmnt didn't throw up anything useful. Are there any more syslinux.cfg files I do not know about?

Thanks for the swift answer.

Pete.

Comment: Well how exactly did you install syslinux? For example, what path did you specify for `extlinux --install`? Is `/boot/syslinux/` empty? If not is there a file named `ldlinux.sys` (not `ldlinux.c32`)?

Comment: I installed Knoppix from the live DVD. There is a /boot directory, but no syslinux directory in that and no file called ldlinux.sys. The only syslinux.cfg are located in /mnt-system/boot/syslinux/syslinux.cfg and /home/knoppix/Desktop/KNOPPIX/boot/syslinux/syslinux.cfg. I have edited both of these but to no effect.

Comment: @user3198479 sorry, i didn't really know about knoppix, updated my answer

Comment: there is no ldlinux.sys, just a load of non-ascii files ending in .32.

Comment: @user3198479 what? have you read my updated answer?

Comment: Just read your update, works like a treat, thank-you very much, this has saved me hours of head scratching! You're the man!